# Defining a linear functional on a subspace of the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $(x^*_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of linear functional on a vector space $E$ over a field $K$ and $(\eta_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of elements of $K$. Let $F'$ be the span of $(x^*_i)_{i\in I}$ in $E^*$.

Suppose for all $\rho\in K^{(I)}_d$ such that $\sum_{i\in I}x^*_i\rho_i=0$ we have $\sum_{i\in I}\eta_i\rho_i=0$. The author asserts that this condition implies that there exists a linear mapping $f:F'\rightarrow K$ such that $f(x^*_i)=\eta_i$ for all $i$. I don't see what justifies the existence of such a linear map. Explanation please?

**Edit:**

There exists some  $J\subset I$ such that $(x^*_i)_{i\in J}$  is a basis of $F'$. Then there exists a linear mapping $f:F'\rightarrow K$ s.t. $f(x^*_i)=\eta_i$ for all $i\in J$. Is there way to extend the equalities to the all of $I$?

Comment: What is $K^{(I)}_{d}$?  Or, does the sentence where you have this symbol serve as the definition of this symbol?  In particular, what does the subscript $d$ signify?

Comment: Also, the language and notation of the statement seem to be a lot more complicated than the content.  Suppose I asserted that there is a family $(x_{i})_{i \in I}$ of vectors in $E$ such that
$$
x_{i}^{*}(x_{j}) = \delta_{ij} \mbox{ for all } i, j \in I.
$$
Does that appear plausible?  If so, how would you prove it?